# Foundry Build Error with Custom Library for xgboost.spark - Cross Dependency Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I am currently  facing an issue with Palantir Foundry's platform.
I have created a custom library to use the xgboost package on PySpark within Foundry (xgboost.spark). However, I'm encountering a problem during the check before the build process. I will attach a screenshot of the error along with this post.

[image]

I suspect that this may be a cross-dependency issue. The libraries that I use in the repository in question are:

```
- python (v3.8.*)
- transforms (in 'recommended version')
- transforms (in 'recommended version')
- transforms (in 'recommended version')
- foundry_ml (v3.126.0)
- pyyaml (v6.0)
- hyperopt (v0.2.7)
- numpy (v1.19.5)
- setuptools (v65.6.3)
```

I have tried various version combinations, including setting all libraries to their recommended versions, but the issue persists.

I also tested in a blank repository, the code of the custom library passes the checks and runs. The problem comes (I guess) from the dependency versions.

Any assistance or guidance on resolving this error would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: why do you have three times transforms?